# recognize when application returns from blank screen

Tags: android, onresume

Is it possible to get know when my application returns to view for user, after blanking screen? In this moment application calls method onResume, and my application has crash. ("has stopped unexpectedly") I know why and I can repair this problem, but I need to know when application returns from blank screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the point when user unlocks the device - [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) is what you need. If this is not the case - please elaborate and post more details

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the point when user unlocks the device. How can I use the ACTION_USER_PRESENT? In this point onResume() method is calling. So can I in this method recognize that ACTION_USER_PRESENT has been used?

Comment: You register a receiver that listens to `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT` intents and notifies your app

Comment: could you give me some example? I supose I have to use BroadcastReceiver? And how can I use the message form thie receiver in onResume() method?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "after blanking screen" ? like if the screen times out and turns off? Either way it will be mostly impossible for us to help you with only the information you've given. Post the code from your onResume() method, also look in the Logcat and copy the stack trace that comes from the exception you're getting. Post that here too. Once you have done this it is far more likely that we can help you resolve the problem.